# Logstash syslog input from nginx

Tags: nginx, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, syslog

I have a ELK server, and receive logs from remote nginx servers.
I created two logstash configuration files, for different inputs.
Firs config listen to 5140 port`

```
input {
  syslog {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => 5140
        timezone => "CET"
        tags => "test-server-nginx"
        type => "log"
        }
  }

filter {
grok {
   match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"]
   overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
geoip {
   source => "clientip"
}

mutate {
   convert => ["response", "integer"]
   convert => ["bytes", "integer"]
   convert => ["responsetime", "float"]
}

date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}

useragent {
   source => "agent"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "test-nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

nginx config is:

```
 access_log syslog:server=my-elk.com:5140,tag=nginx_front_nginx_access;
```

Second logstash configuration is:

```
input {
  syslog {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => 5150
        timezone => "UTC"
        tags => "aws-nginx"
        type => "log"
        }
  }

filter {
grok {
   match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"]
   overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
geoip {
   source => "clientip"
}

mutate {
   convert => ["response", "integer"]
   convert => ["bytes", "integer"]
   convert => ["responsetime", "float"]
}

date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}

useragent {
   source => "agent"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "aws-nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

And nginx for this:

```
access_log syslog:server=my-elk.com:5150,tag=bk_nginx_access;
```

I see the input traffic over port via

```
tcpdump 'port 5140' (and 5150)
```

all work fine, i see that the packets is coming.

But when i create a kibana index, and loog to the firs pattern, i see that the two indexes are mixed. 
[First config index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdlG4.png)

[Second config index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGmSt.png)

Please help.
Im also tried use input udp plugin, but no result.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the log_format from nginx ? Thanks!

Comment: log_format logstash '$http_cf_connecting_ip - [$time_local] "$request" '
                                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                '"$http_user_agent" $http_x_forwarded_for '
                                '$request_time "$args" "$request_body"';